# How to prevent iframe to modify top-level browsing context (top.history)?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-history

I try to create some layout management web application that able to host other child applications (same-domain) inside it.

[image: Overview]

Currently, main application can track any navigation in child application and keep navigation record in main application. User can click back or forward button to go to recent page. Everything works just fine until I found some code in child application that programmatically change `location.hash` property or call `history.pushState` method in child application.

Normally, Browser automatically adds the old history state to history stack of child application that's correct. But modern browser always **share history stack** between **main application** and **every other iframes** (child application) that lead to broken history of main application. User cannot click back in the browser to go to previous page that is visited before main application.

According to [W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#the-session-history-of-browsing-contexts)

> The **joint session history** of a **top-level browsing context** is the union
>   of all the session histories of all browsing contexts of all the fully
>   active Document objects that share that top-level browsing context,
>   with all the entries that are current entries in their respective
>   session histories removed except for the current entry of the joint
>   session history.

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to create separated history for each iframe? I try to set `document.domain` like this.

   - main application domain is 'apps.site.com'.
   - child application domain is 'apps.site.com' but I change it to 'site.com' to prevent cross-site scripting. But it doesn't work because browser sync this history not the iframe.
2. Is there any way to prevent iframe to navigate/hashchange/pushState? 
   My current idea is patching every related properties/methods and also listen to `click` event to prevent changing browser history. I'm not sure this gonna work and it seem too risky to do that.

Thanks,

Ref:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#traverse-the-history

Comment: Fundamentally, no. You can google this and come up with lots of answers but the bottom line is that this is the way browsers are designed, and with good reason, to make the behavior of the Back and Forward buttons work in an intuitive way. If the URL of the iframe changes, from the user perspective, "back" should return the world to the state before that URL change. This should not be considered "broken history of main application", but rather "correct history of main application".

Comment: I know. Browser try to simplify multiple iframe workflow. However, this behavior should not work in most case of multi-level nested iframes like my application. I think browser should allow application to manually manage history state.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox

Comment: Even iframe in sandbox, browser still share session history.

Answer (score 0):

I know Chrome have a new  tag, which runs in a separate process than your app. You might check with it: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

But this tag is not something that HTML5 had standardized. Most of other major browser does not support this.

But for the Iframe, the answer is no.

Comment: "Chrome Apps" let you use HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript to deliver an experience comparable to a native application. It's just a tag for Chrome extension not a part of normal web browsing on Chrome.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps